# Restart service with custom path to init.d file

Tags: ansible, aix

I want to restart a service via init.d file on AIX. Ansibles `service` and `sysvinit` didn't work. How to control those services using Ansible.

I know I could run a shell command but maybe there is a builtin solution.

This is, what I would do on a shell:

```sh
/etc/rc.d/init.d/nrpe restart
```

Comment: Well, AIX is an exotic platform. Linux-specific tools are unlikely to work on it without modifications.

Comment: NRPE is working great and Ansible too. AFAIK the `service` module also supports `startsrc`/`stopsrc` on AIX. But I thought there is a way to point the `service` module to this init script. OK, I'm using the command for now.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs of the service builtin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html):

> Controls services on remote hosts. Supported init systems include BSD init, OpenRC, SysV, Solaris SMF, systemd, upstart.

Basically the `service` module tries to auto-detect which init system is used and perform the action using that init system. But if your init system does not know about the service (you are running the init script directly, right?) it (the init system) will not be able to restart it.

So you can not use the `service` module or any other module that tries to interact with your init system, if the init system is not aware of your service.

You should put your init script into the correct directory for your init system to recognize it (then you can also run `service nrpe restart`) and then use the `service` module.
If you can not do that for some reason, you will need to use the `command` or `shell` module to restart your service.

Comment: It's AIX. There is no `service` command. The primary service system is controlled via `startsrc`/`stopsrc`. I'm using some tools from **AIX Toolbox for Linux Applications** which install like this.

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm not familiar with AIX. It looked like old init scripts from pre-systemd ages :D
Check out this, maybe you find something usable: https://github.com/IBM/ansible-power-aix But actually, I'd go with `shell` or `command`.